# Mathematically, 1 in 3 and 10 in 30 are equal. What about in probabilities?

Tags: probability

Assume I am in a draw for a prize. There are 3 rubber balls, 2 red ones (loser) and 1 green ball (winner). If the green ball is drawn, I win.

Now let's have a second draw (simultenously). It has 20 red balls and 10 green ones – same thing, 1 draw, if I get a green ball, I win.

Assume equal random distribution of the balls. Is there any difference in the win probabilities between the two scenarios?

---

Side note: In an uneven fight, 2 v 1 vs 20 v 10, I believe the 1 fighter vs 2 has a better probability of winning than 10 over 20 (it's easier to overcome a 2:1 advantage once than it is 20 times). Not sure if it plays into this at all :).

Comment: Could you change the title? Probability is a branch of mathematics.

Comment: That's fair, what I meant is specifically.

Comment: Any time you draw just one ball, and 1/3 of them is winning while 2/3 are losing, your probability of success is 1/3.

Comment: In an uneven fight, 1:2 vs. 10:20 does have an influence, but things like morale or whether the smaller for can hold a chokepoint resp. fighting surrounded in an open field can drastically change probabilities.

Comment: Also, 10:20 is equivalent to doing 10 draws of 1:2, so assuming the 10:20 are 10 matches of 1:2, the probabilities and result distribution will be the same as with drawing balls (assuming a 1:2 fight has a 1:2 win chance, which is usually not the case due to skill level).

Answer (score 8):

The probabilities are the same! However, we would treat the two differently in inference about the proportion.

Let’s construct a 95% confidence interval for the proportion in each case. The usual formula for this is:

$$
\hat{p} \pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}
$$

For 1 in 3 draws, we get:

$$
0.33 \pm 1.96\sqrt{0.33(1-0.33)/3}
$$

For 10 in 30 draws, we get:

$$
0.33 \pm 1.96\sqrt{0.33(1-0.33)/30}
$$

The second situation will give the narrower confidence interval. Likewise, the p-value for a proportion test will be lower in the second case.

However, both cases give the same $1/3$ probability as the $\hat{p}$ proportion.

Comment: I do not think n = 1 or =10.

Comment: $n$ is the sample size, it should be 3 in the first case and 30 in the second. This doesn't change you conclusion however, but it's not surprising that the width of the internal shrinks as $n$ increases (all else equal). Though I don't see why confidence intervals are interesting here, we all ready know the probability distribution

Comment: _"However, we would treat the two differently in inference a out the proportion."_ It appears that OP doesn't know almost anything about basic probability, so explaining inference, and confidence intervals about proportions without explaining what situation you're talking about must be confusing.

Comment: To clarify: If we have a black box random machine, and we get 1 win out of 3 draws, that leads us to different conclusions about the win probability than getting 10 wins out of 30 draws would. That has nothing to do with the 3 or 30 balls in an urn.

Comment: Confidence intervals are irrelevant for the OP's scenario. The answer should be edited to either explain when confidence intervals become relevant, or to not have that part at all.

Comment: If you only draw 1 ball once in either case, the only proportions you can have is either 0 or 1, with a 66% and 33% probably of each. So the proportion distribution doesn't get narrower or change at all if you have 10+20 instead of 1+2 balls. If you were instead solving the problem where you increase the number of times you draw (with replacement) (which wasn't specifically asked), the confidence interval will not be different between 10+20 and 1+2 balls, since, as shown above, the outcomes and probabilities for 1 draw is the same in both cases and multiple draws are independent.

Comment: The focus on confidence intervals doesn't belong here. The contents of the drawing pool are known, it's not like we have a sample of 3 balls or of 30 balls. It makes no sense to build a confidence interval for a parameter estimate for a sample *when you have tested the entire population*. The likelihood of winning in each case is 1 in 3, and there is no possibility that the chance of winning could actually be 32% or 34%. There is zero uncertainty in the likelihood of winning in both cases, it is exactly 1 in 3 for both.

Answer (score 6):

For the ball problem, the probabilities are the same and $1/3$. For truly random draws, it is neither harder nor smaller to draw one green ball in an urn consisting of 1 green & 2 red vs 1K green & 2K red. Your fighter example doesn't reflect the same situation though.

Comment: right the fighter scenario was more along the lines of why i was thinking there'd be a possible difference.

Answer (score 0):

For the ball problem the probabilities are the same because every ball is equally likely to be picked.

In the 3 ball bag there are 3 possible (equally likely) balls. Any ball gets picked on average 1/{number of balls} of the time.  in other words, the probability of getting the green ball is 1/3.

In the 30 ball bad there are 30 possible (equally likely) balls.  Any ball gets picked on average 1/30 of the time.  Suppose all the green balls were numbered 1,2,...,10.

Green1 gets picked 1/30 of the time.
Green2 gets picked 1/30 of the time.
...
Green10 gets picked 1/30 of the time.

So Green gets picked 1/30 + 1/30 + .. 1/30 = 10/30 = 1/3 of the time.

But in the fight

- Not all the fighters are equal
- Even if the fighters were equal (e.g. they were robots) they could gang up.
- Even if the fights were separate i.e. just 10 lots of 1vs2, 1vs2 isn't a random draw. 
  If all the fighters are equal then I would expect 2 ALWAYS to beat 1!